# Фильтрация ListView с использованием группы CheckBox

Tags: java, listview, checkbox, filter

Имеется `ListView`. В нем находятся объекты `Animals` со следующими полями:
`isAnimal`, `isBird`, `isFish` итп. Значения могут быть равны 0 или 1 (по принципу правда/ложь). Необходимо чтобы в реальном времени фильтровался список в зависимости от выбранной комбинации чекбоксов.

Раньше писал фильтр через строку поиска (в адаптер добавлял `getFilter()`), но видимо в случае если фильтровать `ListView` надо через чекбоксы - этот вариант не пройдет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: А что мешает использовать интерфейс `Filterable` в принципе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формировать новый список объектов-моделей Animals по признаку отметок чекбоксов и передавать в адаптер, потом делать ему `notifyDataSetChanged()`, как самый простой вариант.

Если данные хранятся в БД, то делать выборку по отмеченным и так же передавать ее в адаптер, затем обновлять список через `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Вот как-то так и думал, только видимо имелось ввиду: сохранить полный список объектов (на случай отмены всех чекбоксов), сканировать список объектов и удалять из списка, которые не подошли по признаку отметок, делать notifyDataSetChanged()?
В случае же отмены всех чекбоксов - возвращать полный список и снова notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: Зависит от того, где хранятся ваши объекты-модели при выходе из приложения. Лучше не модифицировать полный список, а формировать новый